# Is there any difference between "work all night," "work the whole night" and "work through the whole night"?

Tags: phrases, collocations

Could you tell me if there is any difference between *work all night*, *work the whole night* and *work through the whole night*? For example:

> We are exhausted because we had **work all night**.
>
> We are exhausted because we had **work the whole night**.
>
> We are exhausted because we had **work through the whole night**.

Are all of them natural?

Comment: If it's past tense, all of them should be _had worked_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "night" is not something clearly defined. In some contexts, 'the night' could mean the *late evening*. Others might say "night" ends at midnight, before 'morning' begins.

When we say "*through* the night" it makes it clear you are referring to the *the time when most people would sleep*, that is from the later hours of one day until sometime after sunrise the next day. For example, "*my baby is sleeping through the night now*".

"Worked all night" and "worked the whole night" could be taken to mean that you ended before midnight.

"Worked *through* the night" would mean you did a shift *throughout* the night, into the morning.

For comparison, "worked through lunch" usually means that you did not break for lunch - you worked *continuously* through it.